# Can we use the Date object in ES6 without the new keyword?

Tags: date, ecmascript-6

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/New_in_JavaScript/ECMAScript_6_support_in_Mozilla

> Additions to the Date object
>
> `Date.prototype` is an ordinary object (Firefox 41)

Does that mean we can finally use Object.create and call the constructor to get a functional date object, as opposed to using the `new` keyword? If so, how.

Comment: This means that Date has a prototype that can be extended. Not that you can do `Date.call(Object.create(Date.prototype))` (why would you want to do that, any way?)

Comment: Because we are looking for a way to ban `new` across the board without exception. In the spirit of Javascript The Good Parts. For more https://github.com/joshburgess/not-awesome-es6-classes

Comment: Thanks, funny reading, looks like JS black mass. Any way, that's a spit in the wind. Built-ins are supposed to be newed in ES6, this is the direction in which JS moves. Before going deeper into heretical teachings, I would suggest to check [Exploring ES6](http://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_classes.html#subclassing-builtin-constructors) as salvatory reading.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Does that mean we can finally use Object.create and call the constructor to get a functional date object, as opposed to using the new keyword? If so, how.

No, you can't. In fact, it's step in totally other direction - `Date.prototype` became plain object, and "magic" happens in constructor.

> Because we are looking for a way to ban new across the board without exception.

You can use `Reflect.construct` (but it's just `new` operator as a function) or use `Date` factory methods: `Date.UTC(year, month[, day[, hour[, minute[, second[, millisecond]]]]])`.

Hovewer, using `new` is recommended way to instantiate ES6 builtins and language standard is clearly moving to more classical approaches to creating instances of classes (you can't use `Map` or `Set` without `new` keyword).